# Failed to resolve entry for package "vue-select-3".The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json

Tags: npm

When I tried Vite with this command (npm run prod), I got this problem.

> [commonjs--resolver] Failed to resolve entry for package
> "vue-select-3". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports
> specified in its package.json. error during build: Error: Failed to
> resolve entry for package "vue-select-3". The package may have
> incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.

Notice that I work with Laravel/Vue and Vite

How can I resolve it?